# Can you avoid the division of debt during a divorce (Arizona community property laws)?

Tags: divorce, arizona, community-property

The context is in USA, AZ and with regard AZ community property laws.

Say spouse A gets a credit card and racks up debt on the card without Spouse B's knowledge or consent. The couple had the income to support all expenses and had no need for the said credit card.

How can spouse B avoid taking on liability for this debt in the division of community property?

IS there any legal precedent, in Arizona (or other community property states) that allows an individual (spouse B) from acquiring debt that spouse A acquired during the marriage?

Comment: I'm confused. Why would the spouse want the debt to not be considered- surely they're worse off that way?

Comment: Could you rephrase using A & B to refer to the parties?

Comment: @Studoku The spouse who didn't use the credit card doesn't want to take on liability for any of it.